# Magento getModel('catalog/category') returns empty category name, id and url

Tags: php, magento

I have an extension to retrieve categories from magento. You can see the code below. The code works for several sites but for two of them what I'm getting is empty values. However, it returns the category object but it is just that. When I try to get the name, id or url for category it is empty.

This is how i get categories:

```
    // Load all categories (flat)
    $activeCategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    // Load all categories (tree)
    $categoriesArray = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSort('path', 'asc')
            ->load()
            ->toArray();
```

And after that in the foreach loop I do the followning to create my objects:

```
    // Expose composite category data
    foreach ($categoriesArray as $categoryId => $category)
    {
        // Check if category is not at root category level
        if (isset($category['name']) && isset($category['level']) && $category['level'] > $rootCategory['level'])
        {

            // Remove root category path from category
            $path = str_replace($rootCategory['path'] . '/', '', $category['path']);

            // Explode parent categories
            $parents = explode('/', $path);
            $name = '';
            $url = '';

            // Get category name and urls for each parent
            foreach ($parents as $parent)
            {
                $name .= $activeCategorNamesById[$parent] . '>';
                $url .= $activeCategoryUrlsById[$parent] . '>';
            }

            // Get products in category with their positions
            $currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
            $collection = $currentCategory->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position');
            Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

            // Index category data
            $categories[$categoryId] = array(
                'name' => substr($name, 0, -1),
                'level' => $category['level'],
                'ids' => str_replace('/', '>', $path),
                'url' => substr($url, 0, -1),
                'id' => $categoryId,
                'products' => $currentCategory->getProductsPosition()
            );
        }
    }
```

Currently, I don't have access to those sites' ftp to update my extension manually and I can't update it in the store. I have no idea what the problem is and how I can test it. One of the suggestions was that in those stores they have customized fields for categories to display id, title and url, but still I don't know how to see that. I have access to their magento admin sites but there I couldn't find anything different in general compared to others.

Edit: The following code returns empty array, even though they have categories in their system

```
var_dump($this->getCategories());
```

Additionally, in other sites under `System > Configuration` there is `Catalog`, but for the one that are not working it is `System > Configuration > Catalogue`. I'm not sure there is a difference between them tho.

Answer (score 0):

Where are `$name`, `$path` and `$url`defined

Try

```
$categories[$categoryId] = array(
   'name' => substr($category['name'], 0, -1),
   'level' => $category['level'],
   'ids' => str_replace('/', '>', $category['path']),
   'url' => substr($category['url'], 0, -1),
   'id' => $categoryId,
);
```

Comment: I just updated the code in the question to show where `$name` `$path` and `$url` are defined and set. Can you tell me what is wrong with that?